# Bit compatible with Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bit.dev

Is there a way to generate a component with Vue 2 using Bit? Right now, seems like creating a component comes with Vue 3 as a peerDependency (which is fine since Vue 2 is going to be out of support by December) but I'm asking if there's a specific version to set or something to start developing components using Vue 2?

Comment: Yes, For instance with ```vue-generate-component```, you can create a new component with ```vgc -s home```.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but that's for creating a component itself. I'm asking about creating component(s) in a Bit.dev tool/environment/etc

Comment: I post an answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

No, Bit.dev does not support Vue 2.0

Support for Vue is rather recent, and as such only available from Vue 3 and up. Please consult the [documentation](https://bit.dev).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you already install Bit by a `npm install bit-bin --global`.

First, navigate to your project directory and initialize Bit.

Create a component or generate using `vue-generate-component`.

In your component's `package.json` file, specify dependency like;

```
"peerDependencies": {
 "vue": "^2.6.12"
}
```

Track the component using bit add > `bit add src/components/your-component`.

Once you've made changes to your component, you can tag it;

```
bit tag --all 1.0.0
```

Finally, you can export your component to a remote scope by a `bit export user-name.scope-name`.

*Replace `user-name` and `scope-name` with your actual Bit username and scope name.

*"Note that while Bit supports Vue 2, it's recommended to start using Vue 3 for new projects as Vue 2 is going to be out of support by December 2023."*